# Getting values from .js highchart

Tags: highcharts

Im quite new at android and java. So not asking for definite answer just a right direction. 
Site is using the highcharts, the thing Im getting is a highchart data.

```
http://webpage/javascript/city/newyork.js


new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: { renderTo: 'graph1' },
yAxis: { min: 0, max: 100 },
plotOptions: { line: { dataLabels: { y: 20 } } },
series: [{ data: [95,96,96,45,37,36,42,51,54,61,62,49,42,39,47,56,60,63,61,49,35,35,39,46,52] }]
});

new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: { renderTo: 'graph2', defaultSeriesType: 'column' },
yAxis: { min: 0, max: 3 },
plotOptions: { column: { pointPadding: 0.2, borderWidth: 0 } },
series: [{ data: [0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00] }]
});

new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: { renderTo: 'graph4' },
plotOptions: { line: { dataLabels: { formatter: function() { if(this.x != ' ') return this.y; } } } },
series: [{ data: [1015,1016,1018,1018,1017,1015,1015,1016,1017,1017,1018,1017,1015,1013,1012,1013,1011,1010,1011,1010,1008,1006,1007,1008,1009] }]
});

$(document).ready(
function($){

    $('#sevendays > li').live(
        'click hover',
        function(){
            $('#sevendays > li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('.day').hide();
            $('#chosen-day > div:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').show();
        }
    );

    $('#chonsen-city a').click(
        function(){
            icity = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('#chosen-city').load('/ajax/chosen-city.php', {ig: icity});
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

The thing I need is to get array of the numbers for the graph1, graph2 & graph4 data so i can draw my own graphs. Most tutorials are about json parsing, but since this is not json format Im a bit lost.
Again, just the right direction, some readable material.
Thank you.

Comment: SO you would like to get array of all points in each chart ? or all points from all charts in one array ?

Comment: Array of all points in each chart.
graph4 to ary4, graph2 to ary2 and so on.

Comment: So you need to interate in each chart and push to one global array, all points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the series of each chart and build an array of the y values:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/298/

```
var data1 = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < chart1.series[0].data.length;i++){
    data1.push(chart1.series[0].data[i].y);
}
```

Comment: Soooo as i get the "http://webpage/javascript/city/newyork.js" to a string via bufferreader I dont need to get it to json object, just need to parse it something like this?
`code`
var data1 = new Array(mystring);
for(var i = 0; i < chart1.series[0].data.length;i++){
    data1.push(chart1.series[0].data[i].y);
}
`code`